# почему у меня в коде( в функции employee()) выводится последнии 2 строки none?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, visual-studio-code, pycharm

код:

```
pizza = 4.99
coffee = 1.49
hamburger = 3.49
coca_colla = 1.99
def employee():
    print(f"Пицца = {pizza};")
    print(f"Кофе = {coffee};")
    print(f"Гамбургер = {hamburger};")
    print(f"Кока-кола = {coca_colla};")
def menu():
    account_1 = str(input("Вы сотрудник или покупатель ? \n Если вы сотрудник то нажмите 
y(aнгл); Если вы покупатель, то нажмите n(aнгл): " ))
    if account_1 == "y":
        print(employee())
    elif account_1 == "n":
        print(buyer())
    else:
        print("Ввели что не правельно, попробуйте ещё раз! ")
print(menu())
```

Comment: Наверна пуша код праграмы не правельный.  Зогчем вы вызываити вашы функцыи `menu` и  `employee` из метада `print` еси ани у вас ни чево невозвращаюд?

Answer (score 1):

Уберите print() при вызове своих функций.

Ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
pizza = 4.99
coffee = 1.49
hamburger = 3.49
coca_colla = 1.99

def employee():
    print(f"Пицца = {pizza};")
    print(f"Кофе = {coffee};")
    print(f"Гамбургер = {hamburger};")
    print(f"Кока-кола = {coca_colla};")

def menu():
    account_1 = str(input("Вы сотрудник или покупатель ? \n Если вы
сотрудник то нажмите 
y(aнгл); Если вы покупатель, то нажмите n(aнгл): " ))

    if account_1 == "y":
        employee()
    elif account_1 == "n":
        buyer()
    else:
        print("Ввели что не правельно, попробуйте ещё раз! ")

menu()
```